# List index out of range for my plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, range

I am trying to plot a .txt file of lines of the form:

```
filename.txt  date    magnitude
V098550.txt   362.0   3.34717962317
```

I am trying to plot the date against the magnitude.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#names = '/home/sindelj/research/condensed.txt'
x, y, z= np.loadtxt ("condensed.txt", usecols=(1, 2), unpack=True)

for ii in range (len(names)):
    x.replace('.txt', '.lc\n')
    jd, npmag = ("np.loadtxt /net/jovan/export/jovan/oelkerrj/Vela/rotation/Vela/list.txt", +x[ii])
    plt.scatter (jd, npmag)
    plt.jdlabel ('Time')
    plt.npmaglabel ('Mag')
    plt.npmaglim ([15.,14.])
    plt.show() # after test comment this out
    fileName = names[ii][:-3] + ".png"
    plt.savefig(fileName)

print "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not opening the text file, you're just assigning "names" to be a string.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html